# Video flickering in full screen mode only in chrome and chromium. firefox works fine. intel hd4000, external monitor via hdmi

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, chromium, 14.10

Since I updated to 14.10 I get some annoying flickering while watching video in `chrome` and `chromium`, but only in full screen mode. Firefox works fine, but i prefer chrome/chromium.

It worked fine in 14.04. For some reason I had the same issue with linux mint 17 mate, which I had installed before 14.04.

Dell Vostro 3360
Intel HD 4000, external Full HD monitor via hdmi
Ubuntu 14.10 Unity (it is the same problem with gnome 3).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, usually this problem occurs if you have increased your display size to more than 100%. Go to display settings and revert back to 100% scaling. It should work